# Проблема с правами

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache2

Я разрабатываю сайт с компонентами Symfony.

Когда ставлю на папку проекта права `$USER:$USER` не работает twig:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory (cache/view/5a). in /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Cache/FilesystemCache.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(349): Twig\Cache\FilesystemCache->write('cache/view/5a/5...', '<?php\n\nuse Twig...')
#1 /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(309): Twig\Environment->loadTemplate('__TwigTemplate_...', 'Index/index.twi...')
#2 /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(277): Twig\Environment->load('Index/index.twi...')
#3 /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/core/View.php(25): Twig\Environment->render('Index/index.twi...', Array)
#4 /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/pages/Index.php(16): core\View->render(Array)
#5 /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/core/Router.php(126): pages\Index->__construct()
#6 /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/core/Router.php(25): core\Router->createPage(Array)
#7 /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/core/App.php(18): core\Router->run()
#8 /va in /var/www/mvc.loc/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Cache/FilesystemCache.php on line 53
```

А когда ставлю `www-data:www-data` не работает composer:

```
./composer.json is not writable.
```

Пробувл ставить на папки 755 и на файлы 644:

```
sudo find ..  -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find .. -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Не помогло

Comment: Надо не правами а владельцами рулить. Верните права обратно и установите для всех владельца www-data. Композера запускайте тоже от имени пользователя www-data ( sudo -u www-data ... )

Comment: А что с группой ?

Comment: ну и группу тоже можно, да

Comment: @ArtemGolovko, Sheridan подразумевает, что изменять надо принадлежность не файлов/каталогов, а процессов, их использующих: они должны выполняться от имени одного и того же пользователя. этому же пользователю должны принадлежать и все файлы/каталоги.

Comment: Пусть пишут в разные папки, с разными правами